# VSCode doesn't seem to have a version of autocomplete-paths from Atom?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've used Atom for years for React coding. I've wanted to switch over to VSCode, since it seems that's the direction the community is moving. But one thing has kept me. In Atom, there's an extension called `autocomplete-paths` that allow you to do a relative `import` without knowing exactly where the file is you want to import. So, I could do:

`import MyComponent from 'MyComponent'`

...and then the extension will turn that into:

`import MyComponent from '../../path/to/file/MyComponent'`

Given that my React project is set up to do relative imports, this is a must-have feature for me, since there's no way I can possibly commit my entire project directory structure to memory.

I've looked multiple times at the VSCode Intellisense stuff, but I can't find anywhere in the documentation that explains how to do this.

Am I missing something? Does this feature just not exist in VSCode?

Comment: Looks like this extension may do what you're after: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ionutvmi.path-autocomplete  also check this one: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NuclleaR.vscode-extension-auto-import

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core issue you seem to be after is automatically adding imports. VS Code supports that [out of the box for JavaScript and TypeScript](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_auto-imports). Extensions can add this for other languages as well.

Automatic imports work in a different way that you ask for but solve the same problem. In VS Code, to add an import you'd type `MyComponent` somewhere in the file and accept the suggestion for it. Accepting the suggestion will automatically add the import.

If you want to force the import paths to always be relative, set: `"javascript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "relative"`

Comment: Hmm...interesting. I'm not quite after automatically adding imports. I see now that VSCode can do it, but I like to keep my imports organized, and VSCode just drops the import statement at the end of my existing imports, which is never where I want it to be. It also appears to sometimes stick the import statement inside another import statement, which is obviously broken. But I can work with this. It's still not what I want, but I can work with it for now. Thanks! I'll accept this as the "correct" answer, but if a more close match comes along, I'll switch it.